# Add a 'no fast forward' switch when branch to be merged contains multiple commits

Tags: git

In a team we have a convention that:

- when we merge a feature branch which contains only **one commit**, we use **fast forward merge**
- when the feature branch contains **multiple commits**, we use a **non fast forward merge**

Is there a possible script/alias/switch/whatever that would automate it, so that I can always use the same command and the `--no-ff` switch is somehow added automatically?

Comment: I would assume you'd need to write such a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```bash
#!/bin/sh

# Arg 1: The branch that you want to merge into the currently checked out
# branch

set -u

count=$(git rev-list --count HEAD..$1)
if [ $count = 1 ]; then
    git merge --ff-only $1
else
    git merge --no-ff $1
fi;
```

You can also add some more logic:

- Rebase instead of fast-forward

  - It often happens that upstream moves ahead of feature branches before
    they are ready to be merged
  - This script will fail with `Diverging branches can't be fast-forwarded` if the branch is behind the currently checked out
    branch
- Edit the commit message

  - I often “squash” one-commit PRs that I’ve made and then edit the
    commit message to point to the PR that it came from
- Of course now it’s not a non-fast-forward merge again

Comment: `set -u` might help give a more useful error when the user omits to supply an argument.

Comment: @TobySpeight That seems like a Bash builtin? If so yeah, one might want to use Bash on this script so that you can use things like that.

Comment: [`set`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_25) is a  standard POSIX built-in function, and its `-u` option is also specified by POSIX.  So no need for Bash here.